How to align an MUI Collapse table with the main header column?
I am using MUI CORE Collapse datatable, but I want it aligned with the parent row's head column. I think there is a default setting in Collapse. Could you please help?
here is the code
<React.Fragment>
        <TableRow sx={{ "& > *": { borderBottom: "unset" } }}>
          <TableCell className="border-2">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="expand row"
              size="large"
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
            >
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="border-2">
            {row.id}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center" className="border-2">
            {row.date}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center" className="border-2">
            {row.customerID}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center" className="border-2">
            {row.jobNumber}
          </TableCell>
          {Object.entries(row.workStatus).map(([, status]) => (
            <TableCell align="center" className="border-2">
              {status}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
          <TableCell
            colSpan={Object.keys(row.workStatus).length + 5}
            style={{ padding: 0 }}
          >
            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                <Table size="small" className="border-2">
                  {Object.values(row.subWork).map((sub, subIndex) => (
                    <TableRow key={subIndex}>
                      <TableCell colSpan={5} className="border-2"></TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">{sub.jobNumber}</TableCell>
                      {Object.entries(sub.workStatus).map(([key, status]) => (
                        <TableCell key={key} className="border-2">
                          {status}
                        </TableCell>
                      ))}
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </Table>
              </Box>
            </Collapse>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </React.Fragment>


*Work Stutas are same

Same table structure as parent.

